# Call the lastvalue after takeUntil

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have an service call on which i am checking whether it returns true or false every 5 seconds.

```
notifier(){
   return Rx.Observable.of(true) // based on some condition       
}

executeAnotherApiCall(){

}

const interval = Rx.Observable.interval(5000)


interval
  .takeUntil(() => this.notifier())
  .map((x) => this.executeAnotherApiCall())
```

The problem is executeAnotherApiCall is never called, it directly goes to calling method subscribe method.

Is there a way to execute another method/function after `takeUntil()` returns true.

Comment: Your `interval(5000)` emits after 5 secs and then every 5 secs. `takeUntil` emits instantly - before 5 secs passed, so your output Observable completes before it emits any value.

Answer (score 2):

`timer(2000)` works that it emit 0 after 2 second then complete. TakeUntil wait when `this.notifier()` will be complete and stops emit values. Your interval emit first value after 5 seconds so this case will never occur because takeUntil will stop emit values.

When you change the parameters, for example:

```
const interval = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
const notifier = Rx.Observable.timer(2000)
```

your executeAnotherApiCall() method in this case will run once.

Comment: OP doesnt use `const notifier = Rx.Observable.timer(2000)` in his snippet. He's using `this.notifier()`